# SharePoint 2013 check if a list column already has a value and send email

Tags: c#, sharepoint, if-statement, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I have a case with 7 different states. So in state 1, users can fill some fields from a list. And one of my if-statements is when the field "Connect to" is filled with a number, my code sends an email to the user. But they don't have to fill this column only in the state 1, they can also do it in state 2 or maybe state 3.

But the problem is, if they filled this column in state 1 and proceed, then goes to state 2 and 3, the code will recognize that the field has a value and will send another email.

How should I customize my if-statement that if the code ALREADY sent one email, that it shouldn't be sent again? Thanks!

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @tnw How would that help?  What are you planning to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have another column that indicates that you've sent this email. Flip it when you send the email.  Don't send the email if the "SentEmail" column is already `true`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Servy, I was actually thinking about it but wondered if you could do anything in the code instead of adding a new column. Maybe just a bool?

Comment: @user2881765 The code won't propagate state over time.  The list item is where you do that, by storing that information in a column.